# how to override PWA magento 2.4 component main.js file?

Tags: magento2.4, pwa, pwa-theme

I am new for PWA magento but can't understand full structure yet I have installed PWA Venia and want to create override file of venia like in magento we know we create a child theme and can override LUMA theme there, How can we achieve same thing in PWA?

UPDATE
as mention in first comment followed them and get this error

After running this command "yarn workspace pwa-sample build"

yarn workspace v1.22.10
yarn run v1.22.10
$ yarn run build:prod
$ yarn run clean && webpack --no-progress --env.mode production
$ rimraf dist
Error: Cannot find module './src/plugins/normalModuleOverrideWebpackPlugin'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
at require (/var/www/html/magento2/project-community-edition/pwa-studio/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:159:20)
at module.exports (/var/www/html/magento2/project-community-edition/pwa-studio/packages/pwa-sample/webpack.config.js:80:40)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
error Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: /usr/bin/node
Arguments: /usr/lib/node_modules/yarn/lib/cli.js build
Directory: /var/www/html/magento2/project-community-edition/pwa-studio/packages/pwa-sample
Output:

info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/workspace for documentation about this command.

yes is know it says cant find location but file is there is cross checked alot of time but dont know why showing this

Comment: Please check this blog. I think it will help. https://www.ubertheme.com/magento-news/magento-pwa-tutorial-how-to-override-venia-component/

Comment: i have tried that but when i run build command it gives me error dont know whats that

Comment: Can you update the question with the error you are getting?

Comment: question updated